# Zookeeper Heartbeats and Timeouts

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I want to clarify few concepts in Zookeeper with respect to timeouts and heartbeats.

1. What is the the timeout between sending a PING messages from LEADER
   to FOLLOWER? Is it equal to half of tickTime?
2. What is re-connection timeout with respect to clients? Is it equal
   to (session expiration time / total zookeeper servers)?
3. How a FOLLOWER determines that the current LEADER is down or not? Is
   it through a Heartbeat expiry? From tests it looks like that as soon
   as LEADER is down, an exception is fired in every FOLLOWER by
   failing to read an integer(length of the message)